# How I get the current location(frame) from a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, uiimageview

I want to make a custom transition(with `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`). So I present a `UIViewController` modally and then I add a `UIImageView` (to the transition containerView) and set its frame to the selected cell´s frame.

It all works fine, but the frame is not correct, the `UIImageView` is not exactly over the `UITableViewCell` and if I select a cell from the bottom the `UIImageView` starts animating from "start frame" of the cell.

I think I have to update the frames somehow but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution for the misplaced frame can be found in the answer presented by Nick Weaver in this question: [Get UITableviewCell position from "visible" area or window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926554/get-uitableviewcell-position-from-visible-area-or-window)